# linux + disk apears from lsblk but blkid not give the UUID

Tags: redhat, hard-drive, fsck, uuid

we have rhel 7.6 server with sdb and sdc and sdd disks

the machine is physical machines with disk of 1.7T each of them

we notice the sdd disk displayed from lsblk as

```
 lsblk | grep data
sda                8:0    0   1.7T  0 disk /data/sdc
sdc                8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk /data/sdb
sdd                8:48   0   1.8T  0 disk /data/sdd
sde                8:64   0   1.7T  0 disk /data/sde
```

but when we do the following in order to find the UUID number as

```
blkid /dev/sdd
```

then no output

actually we need to get example as

```
 blkid /dev/sdd
/dev/sdd: UUID="941546ac-2168-4130-b51f-f5a255a4e43c" TYPE="ext4"
```

what could be the reasons for that and suggested solution?

*Note - disk with UUID defined correctly in /etc/fstab*

Comment: we not need sudo we have root access

Comment: Blank devices do not have a UUID. Put some filesystem on it first.

Answer (score 1):

If **lsblk** command is working fine in your system then you can use the below command to get UUID of the disk
`[root@ansible-tower ~]# lsblk -f`

Comment: this is what I got lsblk -f /dev/sdb
NAME FSTYPE LABEL UUID MOUNTPOINT
sdd

Comment: as you can see without UUID